# Java Compile Error: Unexpected Type required: variable found: value

Tags: java

I'm getting this Java Compile Error: "Unexpected Type required: variable found: value".

I realize in general, this means I'm probably doing something like 1.0 = mydouble; That's backwards. But, I'm not seeing my error in this code:

```
private Double bid;

public void setBid(double bid) {
    Double.isNaN(bid) ? this.bid = 0.0 : this.bid = bid;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ternary operator can only operate conditionally on values, not entire statements. Therefore, you would need to rewrite your code as:

```
this.bid = Double.isNaN(bid) ?  0.0 : bid;
```

Also, do you have a specific need to declare the field `bid` as a `java.lang.Double` (reference type) and not the primitive `double`?

Comment: Thanks! I made bid an object on purpose because I planned to use it in a GUI table. In order for rows to be sortable, they seem to require Object values instead of primitives.